# python dataframe what apply function per group withouth loop

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have a dataframe

```
df = 
type value
 A     5
 A     7
 B     2
 B     6
 A     1
```

I was to apply function per the groups of the column `type` , so the rank will apply per type and the new df will be

```
df = 
type value rank
 A     5    1
 A     7    0
 B     2    1
 B     6    0
 A     1    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html), setting `ascending=False`:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('type').value.rank(ascending=False).sub(1).astype(int)
```

---

```
print(df)

  type  value rank
0    A      5    1
1    A      7    0
2    B      2    1
3    B      6    0
4    A      1    2
```

Comment: and if I want to apply another function, e.g sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler ?

Comment: That is another question @okuoub . I'd kindly encourage you to ask a new question for that, and limit this one to the originally stated. Otherwise it also could confuse future readers

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a `sort_values` followed by `groupby().cumcount()`:

```
df['rank'] = df.sort_values('value', ascending=False).groupby('type').cumcount()
```

Output:

```
  type  value  rank
0    A      5     1
1    A      7     0
2    B      2     1
3    B      6     0
4    A      1     2
```

Comment: and if I want to apply another function, e.g sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler
?